# Detection a click on array cell

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a game, basically there is a picture that changes in random cell every 1 second

and I want to detect that if someone clicks on the picture that changes it will send an alert

or something like that, any ideas how can I do that?

That's the source: http://pastebin.com/zeLmF4xw

Comment: Eww, will this `document.write` mess ever die?

Comment: @j08691 I don't know how I can detect a click when the mouse is over the changing image.

Comment: @ThiefMaster what do I have to do instead of document.write then?

Comment: have you tried an onclick='checkClick();' added to each image, and will be ok, also you need to close your image tag 'src = 'back.jpg' />' then passin the src to detect what the image is? src = 'back.jpg' onclick='checkClick(this.src);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you could place an onclick onto the image and detec the image src within your check function.

```
  ...
  arr[i][k] = "<img id='imgId" + ("["+i+"]["+k +"]") + "' src = 'back.jpg' onclick='checkClick(this.src);' />";
  .....

 function checkClick(e)
     {
      alert(e);
     }
```

this should alert the name of the image

Answer (score 1):

if each picture has an id(it should) then use jquery

```
$('#id_of_the_pic').click(function(){
  alert('you just clicked it')

});
```

no jquery?

```
<img src="images/audio_link.png" id="83" onclick="showme(this.id)" alt="whatever"/>

<script>
function showme(x){

alert('you just clicked - ' + x);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though it's not the situation, I'm having an array, look how the code is being implemented.

Comment: @idish when you take about im having an array, can you explain a little more as the answer is similar to mine but you need to be a little clearer to what your after, if this is not, thanks

Comment: @SimonDavies You're right, I'll be clearer on future questions, thank you for your help.

Comment: @idish not a problem, it took me a while and probably still learning